# pygame how to make the map scroll automatically

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to make a game where you need to avoid obstacles while the map scrolls automatically. So far, I've taken some code from someone else in an attempt to repurpose it, but I'm having some trouble. I'm a novice to pygame, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to simplify this code, but whenever I change a line, something breaks. I don't need any gravity, and I would like to move up and down at will (kind of like R-Type or one of those other old space shooters). The most important part is to make the map scroll from right to left on its own, and if the player touches a wall, the player dies.

I understand I need to tell it to move everything around the player, but I'm not sure how to express that in this code.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Use arrows to move!")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP  PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                                                                                               P  P                                                                                                                                                                                                           E",
        "P                                                                                               P  P                                                  PPP                                                                                       PPPPPPPPPPPPP                                                  E",
        "P                                                                                               P  P                                                  PPP                                                                                       PPPPPPPPPPPPP                                                  E",
        "P                                                                                               P  P                                                                                                      PPPPPPPPP                                                                                            P",
        "P                                                            PPPP                               P  P                                                                                                      PPPPPPPPP                                                                                            P",
        "P                                                            P  P                               PPPP                               PPP                                                                                       PPPPPPPPPPPP                                                                      P",
        "P                                                            P  P                                                                  PPP                                           PPP                                         PPPPPPPPPPPP                                                                      P",
        "P                                                            P  P                                                                  PPP                                           PPP                                                                                                                           P",
        "P                                                            P  P                                                                                                                PPP                                                                       PPPPPPP                                             P",
        "P                                                            P  P                                                                                                                                                                                          PPPPPPP                                             P",
        "P                                                            P  P                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP  PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP"]

    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    total_level_width  = len(level[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level)*32
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        camera.update(player)

        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        pygame.display.update()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10
            pass
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    print "collide right"
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    print "collide left"
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#DDDDDD"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks to Dominic Kexel for providing most of the code.

Comment: i suggest to make a blank game, and step by step recreate what you have now. That way you will know what exactly does what, and it will be easier to make modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a camera here is the wrong approach; I would rather move the blocks around by themselves.

Take a look at this simple example (it should get you started):

```
import pygame

lvl = """
##################################################################
                                      #      #                    
 #          #           #                                    #    
                            #   #     #         #                 
                #                               #     #        #  

                        #          #         #            #       
         #       #      #   #                      #           #  
   #                        #                #                    
          ####       #              #                 #           
    #                       #       #        #                    
##################################################################"""

# initialisation
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
lvl = lvl.split('\n')[1:]
TOTAL_H, TOTAL_W = len(lvl)*32, len(lvl[0])*32
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, TOTAL_H))
LEVEL_SPEED = 5
player, PLAYER_SPEED = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 32, 32), 4
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 52)
text = font.render('FAILED !', True, (255, 0, 0))
timeout = 0

# create Rects that represent the level
x, y = 0, 0
blocks = []
for line in lvl:
    for char in line:
        if char == '#':
            blocks.append(pygame.Rect(x*32, y*32, 32, 32))
        x += 1
    x, y = 0, y + 1

run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            break

    if timeout:
        timeout -= 1
    else:
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: player.move_ip(0, -PLAYER_SPEED)
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: player.move_ip(0, PLAYER_SPEED)
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: player.move_ip(-PLAYER_SPEED, 0)
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: player.move_ip(PLAYER_SPEED, 0)

    for block in blocks:
        # move each block
        block.move_ip(-LEVEL_SPEED, 0)
        # collision detection
        if not timeout and block.colliderect(player):
            timeout = 100
        # if blocks move out of view, 
        # let'm reappear on the right to
        # create an endless loop
        if block.right < 0:
            block.move_ip(TOTAL_W, 0)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for block in blocks:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200, 200, 0), block)

    if not timeout:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 200, 200), player)
    else:
        screen.blit(text, (200, 150))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(40)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help! I do have one more question though: What would be a good mode of incorporating textures for the moving 'walls'? I've looked into building tiles in PyxelEdit and Tiled. Would it be easy to substitute an image for one of those '#' blocks?

Comment: Sure. Instead of `pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200, 200, 0), block)` just blit an image, e.g. `screen.blit(block_image, block)` where `block_image` is an image you loaded at the start of your game, e.g. `block_image = pygame.image.load('your/file/name.jpg').convert()`

Comment: Or use block_image = pygame.image.load('red.png').convert_alpha(), this does not mess up the image quality.

Comment: @froost1999 this has nothing to do with the image quality. `convert_alpha` just adds an alpha channel.

Comment: Well I tried to do it in my answer with your method and mine and with my the quality was better.Not smugged.